# Python looping error counter

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm trying to drop columns in my DataFrame and I would like to ask why can't i iterate a series in my function. Here is my code

```
def checkDropVariance(df, column):
    percentage = df.groupby(column).size().sort_values(ascending=False)/len(df) * 100
    mean = percentage.mean()
    N = len(percentage)
    variance = 0
    for i in range(N):
        variance = variance + ((percentage[i]) - mean) ** 2
    variance = variance/N
    if variance > 10:
        df = dropCol(df, column)
    return df
```

However outside the function, if I do something like:

```
percentage = df.groupby('grade').size().sort_values(ascending=False)/len(df) * 100
percentage
percentage[2]
```

I get

```
grade
B    28.822392
C    27.705086
A    16.809648
D    15.621800
E     8.012288
F     2.412106
G     0.616680
dtype: float64

16.809648424166571
```

The KeyError returns 0
I found that if I change the i in percentage[i] to 5, i got KeyError returns 5
Here is the error code:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-2e9f3e36e2d6> in <module>()
      1 for i in df.columns.values:
----> 2     df = checkDropVariance(df, i)

<ipython-input-32-126f83f240cc> in checkDropVariance(df, column)
      5     variance = 0
      6     for i in range(N):
----> 7         variance = variance + ((percentage[i]) - mean) ** 2
      8     variance = variance/N
      9     if variance > 10:

/home/atmaja/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    599         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    600         try:
--> 601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    602 
    603             if not is_scalar(result):

/home/atmaja/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2426         try:
   2427             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2428                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2429         except KeyError as e1:
   2430             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4363)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4046)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13913)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13857)()

KeyError: 0
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the stack trace that the error is occuring on the line:

```
variance = variance + ((percentage[i]) - mean) ** 2
```

This is because `percentage[i]` is pandas way of saying: give me the data from `percentage` dataframe column called `i`.  But `i` is `0` in this case, and your dataframe called `percentage` has no column called `0`.  So you're getting a KeyError.

It seems you are not quite grasping how to use pandas.  [Pandas has a built-in variance function.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.var.html)  You could make a function that drops columns with variance higher than 10 like this:

```
def checkDropVariance(df, column):
    # get the variance of column data
    v = df[column].var()
    # drop the column if the variance is higher than 10
    if v > 10:
        df = df.drop(column, axis=1)
    return df
```

The [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) are great, I would recommend reading through them.

Answer (score 0):

KeyError is coming from `pandas` because `percentage[i]` attemps to access column "i" (not column at position i). If you want to access the i'th column, you would want to use `.iloc` as detailed in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). That is, unless your columns are named as integers, in which case it should work.

Ie,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3))
print(df)

print(df[2])
```

Gives

```
          0         1         2
0  0.727617  0.920699  0.916352
1  0.985916  0.405609  0.123758
2  0.230229  0.981319  0.182571

0    0.916352
1    0.123758
2    0.182571
```

But running that code with `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3),columns=['A','B','C'])` will yield a KeyError.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Unfortunately I can't upvote since I have no reputation.